# Why do I get an error In Accessing File for Bash Code

Tags: shell, random

I Wanted to Make A Game To Just Spend Some Time Improving My Programming Skills..
I Got An Error, I tried Every Thing To Try To Fix It, Is There Any Solution?
This is The Code

```
random=$((1 + $RANDOM % 10))
read -p "Enter A UserName" name
if [ -d $name ]
then
    cd $name
    if [ -d Scores ]
    then
        cd Scores
        else
                mkdir Scores
                cd Scores
                cd ../../
    fi
else
    mkdir $name
    cd $name
    mkdir Scores
    cd Scores
    cd ../../
fi
echo 'enter a random number'
read -p "Enter" r
if [ $r = $random ]
then
        echo 'great' $name
else
        echo 'nope' $name 'the number was' $random
fi

echo 'want to play again(y for play again n for dont play again)'
read m
if [ $m = y ]
then
        chmod +x AnswerDebug.sh
    bash AnswerDebug.sh
elif [ $m = n ]
then
        echo 'end of game'
else
echo 'not an input' $name
fi
```

The Output Was :
[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seo7D.png)

I was programming a game where we have to find a random number. I tried to make a Scoring System but it is unfinished

I expected it to work finely but for some reason the code isn't working
The code can't access AnswerDebug.sh(The Name Of The File)

Comment: Put a `pwd` command just before `chmod` command to see the current directory and check if `AnswerDebug.sh` is into

Comment: Please make it clear: The `chmod AnswerDebug.sh` does NOT produce an error, but `bash AnswerDebug.sh` DOES produce an error? In this case, we need to see the **exact** error message. One possibility would be that AnswerDebug.sh has no _read_ permission. In this case, you would change the unnecessary `chmod +x` into `chmod +r`.

Comment: Please be a bit more informative when asking here for help.... _I Got An Error_  : To mention this is meaningless, unless you also post the error message.  _I tried Every Thing To Try To Fix It_ : To mention this is meaningless, unless you describe what you tried.

Comment: If $name exists you cd into it. Then if Scores exists you cd into it but never cd back 2 directories.

Answer (score 0):

All of this

```bash
if [ -d $name ]
then
    cd $name
    if [ -d Scores ]
    then
        cd Scores      # <<< missing cd ../.., but why are you changing directories?
        else
                mkdir Scores
                cd Scores
                cd ../../
    fi
else
    mkdir $name
    cd $name
    mkdir Scores
    cd Scores
    cd ../../
fi
```

can be replaced by one command

```bash
mkdir -p "$name/Scores"
```